# LibXML: "xmlns" attribute being reported but not in XML input file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML file `sheetX.xml` (taken from an Excel XML sheet file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
           xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"
           xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"
           xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2"
           xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3"
           mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3"
           xr:uid="{109BF357-4A9A-4969-B57D-8A2B0130DC3F}">
  <dimension ref="A1"/>
  <sheetViews>
    <sheetView tabSelected="1" topLeftCell="M1" workbookViewId="0">
      <selection activeCell="A1" sqref="A1"/>
    </sheetView>
  </sheetViews>
  <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>  
  <sheetData/>
  <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

I am reading the file with the [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) Perl module

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location => sheetX.xml);
$reader->read();
while($NERROR1==0){
    my $doc = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    if(!defined $doc){
        $NERROR1=-1;
    } else {
        if($reader->attributeCount()>0){
            print "tag name:" . $reader->name() . "\n";
            my @attributelist = $doc->attributes();
            for my $iAtt (0 .. scalar @attributelist-1){
                print "Att name:" . $attributelist[$iAtt]->nodeName() . "\n";
                print "Att value:" . $attributelist[$iAtt]->value . "\n";
            }
        }
        $reader->nextElement();
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

The output for some of the tags from the perl module are:

```
tag name:worksheet
Att name:mc:Ignorable
Att value:x14ac xr xr2 xr3
Att name:xr:uid
Att value:{00000000-0001-0000-0400-000000000000}
Att name:xmlns
Att value:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main
Att name:xmlns:mc
Att value:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006
Att name:xmlns:r
Att value:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships
Att name:xmlns:x14ac
Att value:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac
Att name:xmlns:xr
Att value:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision
Att name:xmlns:xr2
Att value:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2
Att name:xmlns:xr3
Att value:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3
```

and

```
tag name:sheetView
Att name:tabSelected
Att value:1
Att name:topLeftCell
Att value:M1
Att name:workbookViewId
Att value:0
Att name:xmlns
Att value:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main
```

and

```
tag name:sheetFormatPr
Att name:defaultRowHeight
Att value:15
Att name:x14ac:dyDescent
Att value:0.25
Att name:xmlns
Att value:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main
Att name:xmlns:x14ac
Att value:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac
```

So, basically, the code is printing out `xmlns` attributes that are not shown in the XML file for the `sheetView` and `sheetFormatPr` tags, but the `worksheet` tag has all the attributes that are shown in the file and no extra ones.

At some stage I will need to reconstruct the XML file from the data generated by my perl program (the program also prints out tags, values, etc.). So my question: Is there any way to get my perl program to print out the tags that are displayed in the XML file and not the other ones that are not displayed?

Comment: Are you referring to the `xmlns` attributes?

Comment: Yes, they are not displayed in the xml file for the "sheetView" and "sheetFormatPr" tags but found by LibXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the minimal set of changes I know of to exclude the `xmlns` attributes.  Note changed lines marked `###`.  I am not sure what your other code may be doing with `$NERROR1`.  I removed it here for simplicity.  Most of this is adapted from the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location => 'foo.xml' );
$reader->read();

###my $NERROR1;              # Needed to add this because of `use strict`
###while($NERROR1==0){
while($reader->read) {       ### Per the docs.
    my $node = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);    ### Might not be a document, so $node instead of $doc
###    if(!defined $doc){
###        $NERROR1=-1;
###    } else {
        if($reader->attributeCount>0){
            print "tag name:" . $reader->name . "\n";
###            my @attributelist = $doc->attributes();
###            for my $iAtt (0 .. scalar @attributelist-1){
            for my $att ($node->attributes) {           ### Simpler form of the loop --- don't need the indices.
                next if $att->nodeName =~ /^xmlns\b/;   ### <== The key - skip to the next attribute if this one starts with "xmlns"
                print "Att name:" . $att->nodeName . "\n";
                print "Att value:" . $att->value . "\n";
            }
        }
###        $reader->nextElement();
###    }
}
$reader->close();
```

**Output**

```
tag name:dimension
Att name:ref
Att value:A1
tag name:sheetView
Att name:tabSelected
Att value:1
Att name:topLeftCell
Att value:M1
Att name:workbookViewId
Att value:0
tag name:selection
Att name:activeCell
Att value:A1
Att name:sqref
Att value:A1
tag name:sheetFormatPr
Att name:defaultRowHeight
Att value:15
Att name:x14ac:dyDescent
Att value:0.25
tag name:pageMargins
Att name:left
Att value:0.7
Att name:right
Att value:0.7
Att name:top
Att value:0.75
Att name:bottom
Att value:0.75
Att name:header
Att value:0.3
Att name:footer
Att value:0.3
```

#### Explanation

I found a [PerlMonks thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1128682) that links to [RFC 4918, p. 40](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#page-40), which clarifies that

> Since the "xmlns" attribute does not contain a prefix, the namespace applies by default to all enclosed elements.

In this case, the `<worksheet>` tag declares the default namespace `xmlns="http://schemas...2006/main"`.  That applies to the contained elements, so the `<sheetView>` and `<sheetFormatPr>` tags inside `<worksheet>` also have that default namespace.  XML::LibXML::Reader is giving you access to that information by reporting an `xmlns` attribute on those nodes.